# Switch between windows of unique applications (not Alt+Tab or Alt+`)

Tags: shortcut-keys, window, application-switcher

I'm aware that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> lets you switch between all windows and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> lets you switch between windows of the same application.

Is there any shortcut to switch between windows of unique applications?

For eg., consider that I have these windows running [`Firefox Window 1`, `Firefox Window 2`, `Firefox Window 3`, `Terminal Window 1`], in the most recently opened order (so currently `Firefox Window 1` is active). If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I'll switch to `Firefox Window 2`. Even if I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, I'll switch to `Firefox Window 2`. My question asks for a method, if exists, to switch to `Terminal Window 1` directly.

P.S. I'm also aware of desktops. Just a question out of curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts", you could set "Switch Applications" to for example  <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and leave "Switch Windows" to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then, the latter would retain its default function in Ubuntu and let you switch through windows, whereas the former would allow you to switch applications.

If you would prefer both <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch applications, you will need to configure that with a command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Alt>Tab', '<Super>Tab']"
```

will do that. That is actually the default behaviour in the upstream Gnome Shell.

In "Settings" - "Keyboard Shortcuts", you can at any time revert the keyboard assignment to the default by clicking the little cross that appears next to the changed binding.